# Java Desktop opens files with different extensions

Tags: java, desktop-application, r.java-file

I am using Desktop class to open files like `.txt` files, `.pdf` files, images, etc; I have a problem that when I open first file, lets say a `.jpg` file, the images are displayed in the image viewer, then I try to open a `.pdf` document, the Desktop object tries to open the `.pdf` file with the image viewer, and it fails.

When I open the `.pdf` file first, it opens correctly. After that when I try to open a `.jpg` file, it is opened in the pdf browser. And so it fails...

In short, the first program associated with the first file, is used to open all the other files.
how can I solve it ?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. What is your OS and Java version? Also can we see your code?

Comment: What is your image viewer? Is it one of default Windows? If you open `.jpg` in file explorer, then open `.pdf` in file explorer, is the latter opened in `.pdf` application?